# vite build always using static paths

Tags: vite

I have a simple setup with an index.html, some js file and a sass file, building it with vite. I am using vite defaults without a config file.

After running a build the index.html in the dist folder references everything as static paths:

```html
<head>
  <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.b850bc1f.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.04d1c13d.css">
</head>
```

The same happens to url() paths in css: They are turned into static paths as well.
My question is: Is there a configuration option to make vite output relative paths, so:

```html
<head>
  <script type="module" crossorigin src="assets/index.b850bc1f.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/index.04d1c13d.css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

This leading path is the base URL, configured by the [`base` option](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base), which is `/` by default.

You can remove the base URL by setting `base` to an empty string, making the path relative to its deployment directory:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  base: '', 
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-remove-base-url?file=vite.config.js)

Comment: Perfect!  `base: './'` works, too!  I like to be explicit about relative paths and it also suggests what base is for to my future devs and myself (in case I need to CTRL-F).

Comment: For me, the static path don`t change.

Comment: For me that leads to Vite adding full path from drive to the result! That is, "../../../../my_projects/my_project/assets/index-923869f3.js" Looks as complete nonsense.

Comment: @ArseniiFomin Had something similar happen to me with `base: './',` in my vite.config.ts, though it only seems to occur when using `watch` on the command line. I'm currently using `vite build --watch --base=/assets/.."` (which it resolves to `/` in index.html, thankfully) to trick it into producing what I want. Weird.