# How can I configure Vite to work with relative paths?

Tags: vite, npm-publish

I would like to build my static HTML site in a DIST folder that works regardless of the directory that it's placed in. I am using *Vite* to build the project. I use `base` to tell Vite where the project is:

package.json:

```json
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build --base=/~henk/projects/myproject/dist/"
    },
```

This works, but now my static website can only be opened while the project is *exactly* in `localhost/~henk/projects/myproject/dist/`

If I move the project files to another folder, it stops working. If I want to publish to github pages, I have to remember to manually change the `base` every time.

Is there a way to make Vite use relative paths?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vite build always using static paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69744253/vite-build-always-using-static-paths)

Comment: Thanks, I missed that question even though I searched for it. Setting `--base='./'` works!

Comment: @Kokodoko please answer this question yourself or set it as resolved in any other way