User relative path to /src/main.js (Vite)
Problem
I've created a Vue application with Vite. Afterwards, I've installed Electron and Electron Forge. If I create and pack the App, all works fine after installing on my Linux system. But on other systems it doesn't work.

The reason is, that the index.html loads the main.js from the absolute path of the /dist/assets/ directory which is not obviously not existing on other systems.
How can I config Vite to use the compiled JavaScript from the assets folder, so I can use the packaged (.deb) file on other systems?
Folder structure
├── dist/
│  ├── assets/
│  │  ├── index-<bunchofchars>.js
│  ├── index.html
├── public/
├── src/
│  ├── App.vue
│  └── main.js
├── forge.config.js
├── index.html
├── index.js
├── jsconfig.json
├── package.json
├── preload.json
└── vite.config.js

Source Code
/forge.config.js
const { FusesPlugin } = require('@electron-forge/plugin-fuses');
const { FuseV1Options, FuseVersion } = require('@electron/fuses');

module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {
    asar: true,
  },
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-zip',
      platforms: ['darwin'],
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-deb',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-rpm',
      config: {},
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives',
      config: {},
    },
    // Fuses are used to enable/disable various Electron functionality
    // at package time, before code signing the application
    new FusesPlugin({
      version: FuseVersion.V1,
      [FuseV1Options.RunAsNode]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableCookieEncryption]: true,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableNodeOptionsEnvironmentVariable]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableNodeCliInspectArguments]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableEmbeddedAsarIntegrityValidation]: true,
      [FuseV1Options.OnlyLoadAppFromAsar]: true,
    }),
  ],
};

/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

/dist/index.html (The exported index.html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/home/author/Desktop/electron-vue-express/dist/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite App</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/home/author/Desktop/electron-vue-express/dist/assets/index-CERdpKdc.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>


author is the replacement for my real name ;)

/index.js
// index.js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const express = require('./backend/app')

function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });

  win.loadFile("dist/index.html");
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();

  app.on("activate", () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow();
    }
  });
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

/jsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}

/package.json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "The Author",
  "description": "A simple test",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "build-start": "npm run build && electron .",
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.4.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-fuses": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron/fuses": "^1.8.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.4",
    "electron": "^30.0.2",
    "vite": "^5.2.8"
  }
}

/preload.js
// preload.js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const replaceText = (selector, text) => {
    const element = document.getElementById(selector);
    if (element) element.innerText = text;
  };

  for (const type of ["chrome", "node", "electron"]) {
    replaceText(`${type}-version`, process.versions[type]);
  }
});

/vite.config.js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import path from 'path'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  base: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/'),
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})


Sounds more like you're not packaging the dist/ folder with your src/ in the bundled application. Notably dist/ is usually used for distributions, not code resources (resources/ or inc/ or somesuch may be a better name). That all said, while I'm unfamiliar with electron/forge, you are missing the files entry for your npm package. I suspect electron/forge likely needs a similar indication that you wish to include those files in your distribution.

Don't you need to bundle for the specific platform?

@kissu It creates a full running .deb file. Is this not enough?

@Rogue But it the packaged app finds the index.html without a problem. I've added the code from the /dist/index.html which replaces the path for the script from relative to an absolute one.

Found a solution that works... See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69744253/vite-build-always-using-static-paths

.deb file is only for Linux tho, not Windows or MacOS.

@kissu I know... I'm using Linux Mint only....

Why did you remove / from <script type="module" src="src/main.js"></script>?
